# How to increase vertical margins of nodes of clustered dendrogram

Tags: css, d3.js

I was able to use [Mike Bostock's clustered dendrogram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7809166) successfully. I want node text to be larger and in order to do that I modified the rule

```
.node {
  /*font: 10px sans-serif;*/
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
```

It is OK. Texts are larger but cramped now because line heights and node circles' positions are constant.

I have tried to add `line-height` property to `.node` class but it did not make a difference.

```
.node {
  /*font: 10px sans-serif;*/
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

If I increase svg's height it is ok, it is distributed equally and distances are increased.

So how can I increase the vertical distances between nodes?

Comment: Of course a line-height doesn’t work, because these are all individual text nodes that are “positioned” at specific coordinates within the SVG. (In SVG, you don’t have a normal “element flow” like you are used to from HTML & CSS.)

Comment: Increase the `height` to make more space.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you should enter this as an answer, and precise that you're talking about the height variable in the javascript code, not a CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the layout used in the example to set the distance between the nodes -- the only way to increase the space is to increase the height of the overall graph. This is done through the `height` variable. If you set this to a higher value, there will be more space between the nodes.